# Convert a string into dictionary with new key names

Tags: python

I have a time string like this:

```
   'value': '2020-03-17T00:37:59.000-07:00'
```

I want to convert it to a dictionary like this:

```
"time": {
            "to": "2020-03-17T00:37:59.000-07:00",
            "from": "2020-03-17T00:37:59.000-07:00"
        }
```

I am able to fetch that above "value" but not bale to convert it to dictionary.

My code:

```
entity_dict = {}
for item in entity_list:
    #print(type(item["value"]))
    entity = item['entity']
    entity_dict[entity] = item["value"]
    if(item['entity'] == 'time'):
        time_entity = item["value"]
        print(type(time_entity))
```

Comment: `to` and `from` values should be always same?

Comment: What is `entity_list`?

Comment: `'value': '2020-03-17T00:37:59.000-07:00'` isn't a valid string.

Comment: it seems that item is a json item, usually json in python is a dictionary, if it is single string it should be {'value', '2020-03-17T00:37:59.000-07:00'}, if you expecting a array of such items it should be {'some-key': [{'value': '2020-03-17T00:37:59.000-07:00'}, {}, {}]} In both keys you could simply iterate through values for item in list(dict.values()), or through pairs for k,v in dict. Others depends on you data structure

Comment: Is `'value': '2020-03-17T00:37:59.000-07:00'` the content of the string (i.e., a string literal with that content would be `"'value': '2020-03-17T00:37:59.000-07:00'"`) or do you already have some dictionary `{'value': '2020-03-17T00:37:59.000-07:00'}` or similar?

Comment: `{'to': item['value'], 'from': item['value']}`…!?

Comment: entity_list is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: the content of value is valid because i am fetching the time i n that value.and yes I have already a dictonary like this:

Comment: {'value': '2020-03-17T00:37:59.000-07:00'}

Answer (score 1):

Try this below:

```
entity_dict = {}
for item in entity_list:
    #print(type(item["value"]))
    entity = item['entity']
    entity_dict[entity] = item["value"]
    if(item['entity'] == 'time'):
        time_dict = {}
        time_entity = item["value"]
        time_dict["to"] = time_entity
        time_dict["from"] = time_entity
        # You can append the time_dict to a output list here
        print(type(time_entity))
```

Comment: thanku so much.I got it now.